# How to connect ADB to remote windows server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, adb, portforwarding, rdp

I work on a remote desktop for development but my android device is connected to my local laptop. I wanted to be able to use ADB device in vscode on the remote desktop and connect to the device attached to my laptop.
Can i know how could I do that?

Comment: ADB uses TCP which can be forwarded: https://www.paincker.com/adb-remote/

Answer (score 0):

if they both connected to the same wifi, I think you can run your app using your desktop or laptop. use ADB but first enable ### usb debug ### and ### wireless debug ### second connect your physical phone where you want to connect your physical phone to for example you want to run the app using your laptop connect your phone to the laptop using usb connector, follow the command here https://www.guru99.com/adb-connect.html after that you no longer need to connect the usb wire. hope I helped